# FortranでC言語でいうところの関数ポインタのようなことがしたい

Tags: fortran

C言語で関数ポインタを用いて動的に関数の中身を変えることができますが、これと似たようなことをFortranで行いたいです。
どのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
int sub(int x, int y){
    return x-y;
}

int main()
{
    int flag=2;
    int(*func)(int, int);
    if(flag==1){
        func = add;    
    }else{
        func = sub;
    }

    printf("%d\n", func(1,2));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[手続きポインタ](https://www.nag-j.co.jp/fortran/fortran2003/Fortran2003_8_2.html)という、関数ポインタと似た機能があります。

例: https://godbolt.org/z/T5zY7rvdM

```
program test1
    implicit none

    interface
        function my_func_type(x, y)
            implicit none
            integer, intent(in) :: x, y
            integer :: my_func_type
        end function
    end interface

    integer, parameter :: flag = 2
    procedure(my_func_type), pointer :: func => null()
    if (flag == 1) then
        func => add
    else
        func => sub
    end if
    print *, func(1, 2)
contains
    function add(x, y)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: x, y
        integer :: add
        add = x + y
    end function

    function sub(x, y)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: x, y
        integer :: sub
        sub = x - y
    end function
end program
```